# Actualización Automatica

Tags: c#

¿Existe en `C#` algún control que permita insertar uno o más registros en una `BD` en un horario determinado?

Ejemplo: tengo una tabla que se llama `tipos de cambio` compuesta por los campos `tc_id identity`, `tc_precio`, `tc_sucursal` y requiero modificar el `tc_precio` a `20.5` a partir de *mañana a las 06:00 am* a 10 sucursales.

Comment: Como tal, no hay. Pero si se puede realizar de otras maneras lo que propones: crear un programa que realice los inserts o updates y que se ejecute mediante una tarea programada en el servidor, o directamente ejecutar las instrucciones en la BD, mediante un trigger, o bien un proceso que corra constantemente  (como un demonio) y verifique la hora y realice las acciones, etc.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario ya me diste una idea de como resolverlo gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear un `job` directamente en la base de datos que ejecute un determinado script de sql (en este caso el que actualiza el precio) y allí en el job le indicas la calendarización:

> fecha, hora, repeticiones, etc

a las que quieres que se ejecute ese script. Todo esto sin la necesidad de programar algo en `C#`. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Un control que realice esto que planteas no existe.

Si necesitas insertar registros podrias crearlos usando un DataGridView para listar los valores al usuario en pantalla y luego al confirmar por medio de `ado.net` realizar los `INSERT` en la tabla de la db

Si conoces sobre ado.net es tan simple como ejecutar un insert de los registros del grid, una estructura como ser

```
string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["keyconfig"].ConnectionString; 


using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring)) { 
    conn.Open(); 

    string query = "INSERT INTO NombreTabla (campo1, campo2) VALUES (@aram1, @param2)"; 
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn); 


    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) { 
        cmd.Parameters.Clear(); 

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["nombreCol1"].Value)); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["nombrecol2"].Value)); 

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    } 
}
```

con esto iteras el grid y se van insertando los registros en la tabla

Comment: Gracias, voy a ponerlo en practica.